# Change Default Keyboard Layout on Lubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, console, keyboard-layout, display-manager

I installed Lubuntu with QWERTY, and now want to switch it to DVORAK.

The documented way to do this is to use the Keyboard Layout Handler on the panel.

This works, but only during and within a desktop session.

For login, the system still reverts to QWERTY, both initial and for any window lock.

The TTY sessions also default to QWERTY.

Is there any way to change everything to DVORAK?

Answer (score 5):

If your system has changed to systemd you should be able to control the global setup with the `localectl` command.  Check the current settings with

```
$ localectl status
```

List the possible keyboard variants, including dvorak, with

```
$ localectl list-x11-keymap-variants
```

Set the new global keyboard and locale with

```
$ localectl set-x11-keymap ...
```

where you need to give, in order, the layout, model, and variant (dvorak). Use the layout and model got from the status output. See `man localectl`.

Normally, the `set-x11-keymap` option is
supposed to change the console tty keymap automatically as well. However, if it doesn't do a good enough job, you can explicitly set the console tty keymap eg with

```
$ localectl --no-convert set-keymap us-dvorak
```

(Use `--no-convert` to not disturb the X11 map).
Use `localectl list-keymaps` to see what dvorak names are possible.

Comment: Thank you -- that fixed the login! 

However, my TTYs still default to QWERTY.

Any suggestions on how to fix those?

Thanks again!

Comment: If by tty you mean the full-screen console, then set-x11-keymap is supposed to change that keymap automatically as well. However, perhaps it didnt find a good enough match. You can explicitly set the console tty keymap eg with `localectl --no-convert set-keymap us-dvorak`. Use `localectl list-keymaps` to see what dvorak names are possible.

Comment: Thank you for the follow-up. I just tried this, and the tty's are still stuck on QWERTY. Also, list-keymaps yields "Couldn't find any console keymaps." Bug?

Comment: Perhaps systemd is not fully implemented yet, so you should use whatever used to be the method in earlier releases. I'm not familiar with that, but there is a [install-keymap](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/install-keymap.8.html) command.

Comment: I was able to execute the command setxkbmap -model pc104 -layout us,us -variant ,dvorak -option grp:alt_shift_toggle using localectl status shows it taking effect, but however, when I press alt and shift key, there is no effect in keyboard layout change, even after logging out, and restart, pressing the toggle key combination has no effect.

Comment: But I found that clicking on the icon of Penguin at the lower right bottom task bar, would make the keyboard layout changed, sometimes, but not always working, it's hard to switch back to my previous layout. I'm using Lubuntu 16.04 with update as of September 22, 2016.

Comment: Since you want only dvorak why don't you try `setxkbmap -model pc104 -layout us -variant dvorak` so you have only one config. I think the effect should be immediate, not needing a restart nor login.